# Sum of rejection matrices of non-parallel vectors is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I need to prove or disprove that if I have n>1 non-parallel unit vectors: $$\{V_1, V_2, ..., V_n\}$$ then the sum of the rejection matrices of those vectors is invertible, i.e.: $$\sum_{i=1}^n{(I-V_iV_i^t)}$$is invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need all vectors to be non-parallel to each other. As long as some two of them are not parallel, the sum is invertible.

Suppose the sum is singular. Then $\sum_i(I-v_iv_i^t)x=0$ for some unit vector $x$. Hence
$$
0=x^t \sum_i(I-v_iv_i^t)x=\sum_i\left(1-\langle x,v_i\rangle^2\right).\tag{1}
$$
However, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $1-\langle x,v_i\rangle^2$ is always nonnegative, and it is zero if and only if $x$ is parallel to $v_i$. Thus $(1)$ implies that $x$ is parallel to every $v_i$. Yet, this is impossible because there is a pair of linearly independent vectors among $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$. Hence $\sum_i(I-v_iv_i^t)$ must be invertible.

Comment: I edited the question they need to be unit vectors

Comment: The formula I-ViVi^t for rejection matrices works only for unit vectors

Comment: no, the number of vectors

Comment: For any unit vector and n = 1 the rejection matrix is not invertible, there needs to be at least 2 (I edit the question again)

Comment: Any rejection matrix of a vector is a projection matrix for d-1 dimensions, so it's obvious that a rejection matrix can't be invertible.

Comment: I don't understand why the last equality is true

Comment: @TomerWolberg $x^tv$ is the inner product of $x$ and $v$ (provided that the vectors are real, not complex).

Comment: Shouldn't there be at least d vectors not parallel to each other (where d is the number of dimensions)?  Because x can be parallel to d-1 unit vectors.

Comment: @TomerWolberg $x$ can be *orthogonal* to $d-1$ linearly independent vectors (I suppose by "$d$" you mean the dimension of the vector space). It cannot possibly be *parallel* to two linearly independent vectors. When $x$ is parallel to some $v_i\ne 0$, it must be a scalar multiple of $v_i$. So, if $v_i$ and $v_j$ are linearly independent, $x$ cannot be parallel to both of them.

Comment: oh right. My bad.